How to find total real roots of $x^4+4x^3+12x^2+7x-3$
Question
The number of real values of x that satisfies the equation:
$$x^4+4x^3+12x^2+7x-3=0$$
Let $f(x)=x^4+4x^3+12x^2+7x-3$
My Approach
$f'(x)=4x^3+12x^2+24x+7$
$f''(x)=12x^2+24x+24$
$f''(x)=12(x^2+2x+2)$
Discriminant of $f''(x)$=$-4$
So, $f"(x)$ is always positive.
So, $f'(x)$ is increasing, and it has one or zero roots.
But, since it is cubic, it has 1 root.
Calculate $f(0)$= $-3$
Calculate $f(1)$= Positive
Calculate $f(-1) = -1$
Calculate $f(-2)= 15$
So, we know that there is a root between $0$ and $1$ and also between $-2$ and $-1$
Now, I'm stuck, How to prove that there are no more roots?
Any hints would help a lot.

Descarte's rule of signs

$f(x)$ is a polynomial of even degree (deg -4) with rational coefficients, so it has either  2 real roots or 4 real roots or none

@Guruprasad What about $x^2(x^2-1)$ ?

@RyszardSzwarc it has 4 real roots

Upon analyzing $f'(x)$,$f''(x)$,$f'''(x)$ [As you have done], we can conclude that $f'(x)$ only has one root, i.e, the graph of $f(x)$ will be similar to a parabola (slope initially is -ve then becomes +ve). So $f(x)$ will either have $0$ roots or $2$ roots.
$f(0)$ gives a negative value also $f(x)$ is similar to an upward parabola therefore it has $2$ roots.

As you have computed,
$f''(x)
=12(x^2+2x+2)
=12((x+1)^2+1)
\gt 0$
and
$f(x)$
has at least two roots.
If $f(x)$ has
three or more roots,
then $f'(x)$
has at least two roots
so
$f''(x)$ has at least one root
which it does not.
Therefore
$f(x)$
has exactly two roots.
